# How to add 2 conditions to new df column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to apply 2 conditions when creating a new df column.

Any ideas on how I should do this?

I want to filter on accounts ending in 5405 and USD currency only.

```
df['Is_Reserve'] = df['Account'].str.endswith('5405') & df['Cur'] = 'USD'
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working example, e.g. a sample of the dataframe you are working with?

Comment: This is just a typo, so the question might get closed. Your last equals sign needs to be a double equals sign, and it probably needs extra parentheses, e.g.: `df['Is_Reserve'] = df['Account'].str.endswith('5405') & (df['Cur'] == 'USD')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is really just a typo, but you could improve it further by using `assign`. If we use this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[["AA5678", "USD"],
["AA5678",  "USD"],
["AA9101112", "DKK"],
["AA13141516","DKK"]], columns = ["Account", "Curr"])
```

We can simply write

```
df.assign(Is_Reserve=lambda d: d["Account"].str.endswith('5678') & (d['Curr'] == 'USD'))
```

which enables us to easily include the transformation in a pandas pipeline by returning the dataframe object directly.
The result is

| Account | Curr | Is_Reserve |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA5678 | USD | True |
| AA5678 | USD | True |
| AA5645 | DKK | False |

Comment: Thanks @academy. Agree I should have posted a working example with the problem. thanks for your solution using lambdas